# I am not able to launch npx create react app. What do i do?

Tags: reactjs

```
Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 18.2.0 (x64) and npm.

C:\Users\aanan>npx create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\aanan\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


Aborting installation.
Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug:
Error: spawn UNKNOWN
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:689:9)
    at spawn (C:\Users\aanan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js:12:24)
    at C:\Users\aanan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:383:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at install (C:\Users\aanan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:334:10)
    at C:\Users\aanan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:461:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from C:\Users\aanan
Done.

C:\Users\aanan>
```

Comment: Some previous stackoverflow questions suggest antivirus causes this:  https://www.google.com/search?q=Aborting+installation.+Unexpected+error.+Please+report+it+as+a+bug%3A+Error%3A+spawn+UNKNOWN+at+ChildProcess.spawn&rlz=1C5GCEM_enUS1006US1006&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: try downgrading your Node.js version. 18.2.0 is not recommended for most users, and may have many bugs like this.